# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object not iterable - What's causing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, typeerror

I'm encountering an error while running my Python script and I'm having trouble understanding the issue. I keep getting the following error message: `"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"`. Can someone help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Here is my code:

```py
def get_input_data():
    # Some code to retrieve input data
    return input_data

def process_data(data):
    processed_items = []
    for item in data:
        processed_item = item * 2
        processed_items.append(processed_item)
    return processed_items

def main():
    input_data = get_input_data()
    processed_data = process_data(input_data)
    print(processed_data)
    # Rest of the code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the script, I receive the error message pointing to the line with the for loop in the process_data function. I've verified that the data variable has a valid value assigned to it before the loop. However, when the loop tries to iterate over it and perform some processing logic (in this case, doubling each item), the error occurs.

Comment: There is not enough code provided to know what goes wrong. You'd need to show us what exactly is going on in `get_input_data`

Comment: It is probable that input_data is None, please provide an example of it when the code fails

Comment: Python doesn't lie to you. If the error message tells you that `data` is `None` then `data` is really `None`. Please check the value again before processing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're experiencing might be due to the `get_input_data()` function returning None, which is causing the `NoneType` object is not iterable error when the `process_data()` function tries to iterate over it.
To resolve this issue, you can check if the `input_data` is None before passing it to the `process_data()` function. Additionally, ensure that the `get_input_data()` function is implemented correctly to retrieve and return the input data.

Here is how you could fix it:

```py
def process_data(data):
    if data is None:
        return []  # Return an empty list or handle the None case appropriately
    processed_items = []
    for item in data:
        processed_item = item * 2
        processed_items.append(processed_item)
    return processed_items
```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).